# Server error, why this error message appears when i use .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

when I use .htaccess file inside a folder named admin with the following code

```
AuthName "Alertme"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /mobs/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

and .htpasswd file with following code

```
rajasekar:66Acdia7gE1to
```

While accessing the file inside folder, it gives server error, **The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request**

why is this happening. help me

Comment: Is your `AuthUserFile` path intentionally `/mobs/.htpasswd`? What happens if you try to `cat` that path in a terminal?

Comment: I'll rephrase what Dominic was trying to say as you didn't seem to understand. /mobs/.htpasswd implies that this location exists from the root directory because of the leading forward-slash. Did you mean that? If not, what is the full path to the .htpasswd file?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely your Apache config does now allow Auth* directives in .htaccess in that directory and/or location. You can check for sure why looking in the error_log for that host. There'll be a line that looks like:

```
[Wed Dec 02 22:13:14 2009] [alert] [client x.x.x.x] /path/leading/to/.htaccess: AuthName not allowed here
```

This error will show up as a "500 Internal Server" error for any client attempting to access that particular server/directory.

You will need to add an "AllowOverride AuthConfig" so Apache will accept the Auth directives in the .htaccess. Details are [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in the Apache docs.

Comment: Agreed. With Apache errors, it's always best to check your log file to see what Apache says is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that /mobs/.htpasswd is absolute (not relative to your webroot) path on your filesystem

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your htaccess and/or htpasswd file can't be read by apache. Either because the user apache is running under doesn't have the needed rights on these files.